# Xamarin/Mono TLS Exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, https, xamarin.android, mono

I am putting together a Xamarin Android project and am trying to build a small app that makes calls to an API. The Xamarin project creates an instance of an ApiWrapper class that I have in another solution and that class is what makes the Http calls (not sure if that's important or not).

The stack trace that I keep getting at runtime is pasted below:

> 06-25 12:36:13.696 E/mono-rt ( 3365): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 
>       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the 
>       request
>
> System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)
>
> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>
> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>
> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I have tried installing the ModernHttpClient and passing in the NativeMessageHandler into the constructor of HttpClient() with no success.
2. Made sure my app has INTERNET permissions
3. Added a custom validator class that returns true and gets passed into `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`
4. Run both `mozroots` and `cert-sync` to try and pull in the proper certificates for the site.

Also, just to be clear, I have a test project that is calling that same ApiWrapper class only through .NET's network stack and it's having no trouble with the encryption and is working properly.

I'm out of ideas and am struggling here. Any suggestions are very helpful! Thanks.

Comment: does the site you are connecting to still have tls1.0 enabled?  error sounds like it is expecting tls1.1 or 1.2.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Is there a good tool to check what version of tls a site is using?

Comment: You can use [this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

Comment: Thank you! I ran the test using the site that @ganchito55 mentioned, and it appears that the site supports TLS 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2. Any other ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to SSL stuff. Wikipedia said that a self-signed certificate was "an identity certificate that is signed by the same entity whose identity it certifies". Isn't this something that is handled on the server side? Or do I have to provide a certificate when establishing a TLS connection?

Comment: Sorry I thought that you had also created the API, If it is online, can you share a link?

Comment: Absolutely! The link is [here](https://api.gwentapi.com/v0)

Comment: I'm a bit new to this. I see the error with my xamarin android application. How can i run mozroots and cert-sync in my xamarin proejct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Integration test was able to call the service and passed but running the code from the Android emulator threw that error. Also tried all the steps you outlined above.

What finally worked for me was changing the settings of the Android project. Right click on the project and click Properties. Go to Android Options and click the Advanced button.

Set..

HttpClient implementation -> Android

SSL/TLS implementation -> Native TLS 1.2+